# How to get a clean screenshot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, opencv, selenium-webdriver

I am working on an automatation program using tensorflow. But i need some data to bypass text based CAPTCHA and i try to gather some data(images actually) from sites. How can i take "clean" screenshots with the help of OpenCV. With "clean" i mean images without white blanks.

Note: I know that we can take screenshot of desired web element using selenium (refer to: https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/screenshots-with-selenium-webdriver/) but in this site there are two text based CAPTCHAs so the screenshot also include white blanks, which ı don't want to have. I also tried capturing images manually but because of my not sensitive hands images also include white blanks.

[When I was trying to get the web element using selenium. I was not satisfied with the result because it has white blanks, which I don't want in my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0uXw.png)

[Normally the images look like that. All I want is getting two seperate images without a white blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HfMj.png)

All I want is getting two seperate images without a white blank in order to use in my data for training. Could you please help me?

Comment: It has to be from real (online) sites? Why not use some captcha generator [captcha 0.3](https://pypi.org/project/captcha/) ? The advantage of this method is that you can enter a text to generate the captcha, so you'll end up with the captcha image AND the label for your tensorflow implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Playwright and take an element screenshot with `omitBackground` enabled: https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.0.2&path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=elementhandlescreenshotoptions